# QuerySelector is not recognising #id with space

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `querySelector` to fetch `div` in order to scroll on that position.

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('#' + i) 
 if (anchor) {
      anchor.scrollIntoView(true);
      window.scrollBy(0, -190); 
    }
```

The problem is that in some divs I have id with space e.g Vegan Pizza (variable i) and in this case variable `anchor` is `null` and scrolling is not working.

Anyone has idea how to make querySelector working with id with spaces?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The space is the descendant selector. For example:

```
#container div
```

will select a `div` which has an ancestor with an id of `container` somewhere, like the div below:

```
<section id="container">
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Use `[id="some id with spaces"]` instead:

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('[id="' + i + '"]') ;
```

You can also use `getElementById`:

```js
console.log(
  document.getElementById('some id with spaces')
);
```

```html
<div id="some id with spaces"></div>
```

But it would be better to avoid putting spaces in IDs - even if browsers can recognize it (using this workaround), it's not technically valid. Consider either removing all the spaces from the IDs, or putting the values into a different attribute (like the dataset) instead.

Comment: To quote the spec: “*The `id` attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.*”

Comment: Further to the previous comment, I forgot to cite my reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute